# What is the best way of replacing a system in a very complex program?

Tags: c++, refactoring

I have a task to replace a library of classes all associated with the same thing. However this thing permeates into the rest of the code to a huge degree. I have been trying to simply comment it all out, but it is taking forever!

Is there a better way? The new system is somewhat similar but not nearly similar enough to just replace the old one.

What's the best plan of attack?

**edit** - My main concern is this -

what if I comment every reference to the old code, and then find that because of the complexity of the system, it still doesn't run. have I then wasted all that time?

Comment: I think refactor is an appropriate tag, if you don't, just remove it.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you removing Thing from your design entirely, or replacing the old Thing library with a new Thing library (with a different interface)? And is the old Thing library itself contained in a tidy source file (or set of them) `Thing.cc` and header (or set of them) `Thing.h`, or is it blended into files with non-Thing code?

Comment: they exist as a collection of files, but it's not very encapsulated and references to the base class exist everywhere. I am replacing the old Thing with a new Thing. The project has about 60,000 files in it.

Comment: Could you possibly post some example code indicating what the old and new systems' interfaces look like, and how complex the difference (and hence the migration) would be?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried that the code won't run after all this surgery, then the goal must be to modify the system gradually and reversibly, verifying that it's still working at every step. *Primum non nocere.*

If you have a good set of unit tests (which I doubt very much, from the sound of this project), you should be in the habit of running it every few minutes. Otherwise you can at least cobble up a regression test of your own: run the code on a typical set of input data, and take the checksum of the output-- if the checksum changes, then you broke something since the last time you ran the test, so rewind to that time (you do use version control, don't you?) and proceed with care. The longer the test takes to run, the less often you can afford to run it, but it should be nightly at least.

The old Thing has not remained encapsulated (if it ever was to begin with). The rest of the code knows too much about the implementation of `oldThing`, making a simple swapout with `newThing` impossible. So clean up the interface.  Look over the `public` declarations of `oldThing` (including whatever base classes are exposed) and consider whether each one is something the world really needs to know about-- if not, put in an accessor/mutator, or revise the class tree, or whatever. Isolate the implementation from the interface.

While you're doing that, look at the public interface of `newThing`; it should be clean and abstract, like what you're trying to achieve with `oldThing` (if it's a mess, then you have a whole other set of problems). With some effort you can guide the changes in the `oldThing` interface to match what `newThing` has.

As that starts to come together, the task of swapping out old for new will start to look feasible. In the end you'll be able to do it by changing a single `#include` statement and a single word in the makefile, if you want to go that far.

Comment: +1, makes sense, and could not be more detailed given the info provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw away all base libraries you don´t want to use anymore, and walk through the resulting error list.

The unsolved references will lead you to where you must get active. If you have replacement patterns for the calling patterns, that´s help.

Comment: it's a fairly opaque process unfortunately - at first you just get a lot of 'this file you're trying to include doesn't exist' errors.. then more and more as you go along removing the offending lines.

Comment: @SirYakalot: If a header was included, chances are that it was used. If it was not used then remove the include, if it was used, then fix that file and move to the next. Also, consider that you won't want to do this in the future, so you might want to think on what the program needs from the library and provide your own interface. Then implement that interface in terms of any of the existing libraries.

Comment: >>it's a fairly opaque process unfortunately<< I don´t see a problem with that?

Comment: opaque is the opposite of transparent.

Comment: Ah yes ok sorry, not a native speaker ;) I agree -- when doing this, you walk deeper and deeper into the dark, creating more and more of a mess. But there is a point where more and more fits together again. I see your point, though (looking at 60.000 files with errors everywhere...urgh).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to shuffle in your 60k files, I'd suggest implementing a dummy version of the existing classes: remove all code done in the original classes and replace all class members by that kind of macro:

```
#define DEPRECATED( function, file, line ) printf("Unsupported %s call in %s line %d\n", function, file, line )
#define DEPRECATED_METHOD_WRAPPER(type, X) X { DEPRECATED( #X, __FILE__, __LINE__ ); return (type)0; }


class OldClass
{
   OldClass() { DEPRECATED( "OldClass", __FILE__, __LINE__ ); }

   // original method
   // int doSomeStuff(int a, void *b);
   // deprecated:
   DEPRECATED_METHOD_WRAPPER(int, doSomeStuff(int a, void *b) );
}
```

Now, when your big program calls your deprecated library, you'll see in the traces:

- the place where it's called
- the method that is called

AND, you don't have to touch the original files for the moment.

Your program will run without it failing, but now your work will be to remove the references of your old classes... but at least you'll get a nice reminder of where they are without perturbating the flow too much.

Comment: The `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in the constructor will point to the header/cpp where `OldClass::OldClass` is defined, and will be of little use.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but at least you'll get notified if one of your old objects is still built somewhere.